# Importing my module and system var on windows

Tags: python, module, python-import

I'm trying "modules". So:

My files dir: `C:\myfiles`
My Python dir: `C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\`

My modules dir: `C:\modules`

Since I want to `import module2` (`C:\modules\module2.py`) from myfile1.py (`C:\myfiles\myfile1.py`) I added a new SYSTEM VARIABLE (Windows).

Name: `PYTHONPATH`

Value: `C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib;C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\DLLs;C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\lib-tk;C:\modules;C:\myfiles`

But... When I try to import, it does not work.

myfile1.py:

```
from module2 import *
```

Or

```
import module2
```

module2.py

```
print("HI")
```

> ERROR: ImportError: No module named 'module2'

Anyone can help me?

Comment: It isn't clear, but have you tried `import sys; sys.path.append('C:\\modules\\')`?

Answer (score 0):

Did You restart console, or open a new console? SYSTEM VARIABLES are visible only on new console session.

Comment: Yes! And still the same! =(